# My whole requires exploration

Tags: riddle, word

My prefix gives out relaxation
My infix takes in much donation
My postfix is 1st in the nation
My whole requires exploration

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Space !!

My prefix gives out relaxation

> Prefix **Spa** gives relaxation

My infix takes in much donation

> I guess it is about **AC** which require more electricity

My postfix is 1st in the nation

> I guess it is about **CE** - chartered accountant

My whole requires exploration

> **Space** : Space exploration is the use of astronomy and space technology to explore outer space.

Comment: rot13(NPR (r.t. svtugre npr) pna or 1fg va gur angvba)

Comment: rot13(Lbh’ir tbg gur evtug nafjre, ohg urer’f n uvag gb svavfu guvatf bss - gur vasvk, cersvk, naq cbfgsvk nyy unir gur fnzr ahzore bs punenpgref.)

Comment: rot13(fhcre CNPf sbe vasvk, nprf ner 1fg nf gebyyrl813 fnvq)